# HTML option и PHP

Tags: php, html, html-select

Как получить выбранное пользователем `value` из `option` с помощью PHP?

Comment: С помощью одного html никак, но при помощи JS можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недостаточно данных. Покажи HTML страницы и PHP-скрипт обработчика.

По тому, что есть сейчас:
Без тега form это делается с помощью JavaScript, вот пример jQuery:

```js
var selected_option = $('#select_id').val();
```

Передать в PHP есть 2 варианта:

1. С помощью ajax,
2. Добавить скрытое поле в `<form>`, куда будет записываться переменная `selected_option` из jQuery.

Comment: а можно ли передать в php напрямую из option ? Добавил html код.

Comment: http://ideone.com/BIjp9h

Comment: @K.Zakhar напрямую ты передать в php можешь лишь через <form>, где указывается скрипт пхп обработчика
Тогда это будет выглядеть вот так:
https://jsfiddle.net/Alexxosipov/k2rgm7kd/ в php выбранное поле будет указываться как `$_POST['name_select'];`

Иначе только через js это делается, поскольку без form ты не сможешь вызвать php скрипт

Comment: это я понимаю , там на самом деле была форма , но я забыл ее указать когда копировал . Все-равно спасибо , уже разобрался! :)

Comment: а, так это сразу нужно указывать)) без формы никак ничего в php-обработчик ты не передашь, только с помощью js